# Некорректное отображение страниц certsrv Microsoft CA

Tags: active-directory

Windows Server 2008 R2. Подняты службы сертификации. Перехожу на страницу certsrv, выбираю подать запрос -> расширенный запрос и открывается страница certrqxt.asp:[image: certrqxt.asp]
Долго бился, пытаясь понять, почему пропускается страница certrqad.asp, пока не решил проверить зайти через IE 8, а в нем, в отличие от IE11, отображается корректно, т.е. после страницы certrqus.asp грузится страница  certrqad.asp:[image: certrqad.asp]

Что может быть не так в IE11 ?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась путем запуска IE11 в режиме совместимости